# Transition-delay does not work on carousel-item

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, carousel, transition

When the carousel item begins to slide , i want it to wait `0.7s` so its content called `bannerContent` animate upward and then 
it slide.

So i gave `transition-delay:0.7s` property to every carousel item but i see before the transition ends the item disappears and its 
`display` became `none`. I think carousel does not take `transition-delay` into account.

Here is what i have tried:

HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
  <div id="banner" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" >
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="bannerContent">
          <h2>Exclusive Luxury Services Group</h2>
          <p>The first; Lifestyle & Business management concierge service in Iran</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="bannerContent">
          <h2>LIFE ELECT</h2>
          <p>first Lifestyle & Etiquette School in Iran</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="bannerContent">
          <h2>LUXELECT</h2>
          <p>first Luxury valuation in Iran</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slider{
  height: 100vh;
}
.slider .carousel , .slider .carousel-inner{
  height: 100%;
}
.slider .carousel-item{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transition-delay:0.7s;
}
.slider .carousel-item-prev, .slider .active.carousel-item-left {
  transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
}
.slider .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left, .slider .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
.slider .carousel-item-next, .slider .active.carousel-item-right {
  transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
}
.bannerContent{
  position: absolute;
  right: 45px;
  top:50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: all 0.7s;
}
.slider .active.carousel-item-left .bannerContent{ /* when the item begins to slide */
  top:-100%;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

Also i tried to use `carousel("pause")` on `"slide.bs.carousel"` event but i saw it is not possible.

How can i make the carousel item to not disappeare before transition ends?

Thanks!